# SSRS How to create horizontal straight line in a Line chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to create a straight line on a line chart showing other data. The line will present what is the good level within the levels for what the original data is actually presenting.

I am trying to create the red line on the attached image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an additional values serie to your chart. Go to Chart Data and press `+` button:

[image]

In expression use the constant value, in your case 180:

```
=180
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This sounds more like something for a **StripLine**.

Comment: It can be done using StripLine or adding other serie (my approach), however in my opinion a StripLine is more complex and wont let set the line dynamically.

Comment: Yes, this was very helpfully, thank you. I was able to add a IF statement to the expression to make the line a bit more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a column of int values at the end of you Stored Procedure (or whatever is supplying your data) and plot it just like any other series.